# How to eliminate internal circuit current consumption from the measurement in bi-directional current measurement circuit?

Tags: current, measurement, bidirectional

I am comparatively new in this domain. I am trying to design a bi-directional current measurement circuit. This is a 5V to 9V DC system. I have two USB C female ports at both ends. Which means I can connect the source and the load in any of the ports. The conventional current flow direction is from USB1 to USB2.

[image: shown in the schematics attached as No. 1]

Where the source Vs is connected to USB1, RiL is the internal load (which is not **Constant**), RL is the load connected to the USB2. This is working fine. I can measure the load current from the shunt. But when I swap the load that is Source Vs connected to USB2 and Load RL connected to USB1, there comes the Internal load current due to RiL.

[image: Riversed current direction]

As now the shunt also measures the current that I am using to power up the internal circuits.

Is there any way that I can eliminate/ignore the internal current usage from the measurement. Is there any techniques or ICs that can achieve that.

Kindly requesting for help.

Comment: You could measure the internal current consumption and calculate the difference.

Comment: I can do that and set it as an offset and subtract it from the total load current. But the problem is the internal current is not constant.